# Is there a color LCD display for an arduino?

Tags: lcd, shields

I currently have a Mega2560 with the LCD4884 Shield. The Shield is good for putting out text and simple pixel images. But I am wondering if there is something that has a full range of colours that would work with the Arduino? The screen size would only have to be a few inches in size.

Comment: I would personally think of this a shopping recommendation. To answer your question: https://www.google.com/#q=arduino+color+lcd

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are actually several shields that have color screens on them. Many of the shields are just regular mini TFT displays, however there are also touch screen ones.

[Here is one](http://www.adafruit.com/products/802?gclid=CK3Mk63SxrwCFedlOgodA3IABQ) from Adafruit that includes a MicroSD holder and a Joystick.

[Here is one](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=12688460&CAWELAID=120125420000001702&catargetid=120125420000031766&cadevice=c&cagpspn=pla&gclid=CMbdyJ_TxrwCFW1nOgodHF4AGg) from Radio Shack that features a 2.8 inch screen with touch capabilities

As far as screen size, many of the screens are only about an 1 inch across, however the biggest I have ever been able to find are 2.8 in.

Comment: The 1.8" TFT from Adafruit with joystick & MicroSD is my favorite thing ever! Display + User Input. Majenko developed an epic library for it: https://github.com/cacycleworks/chipKIT_ST7735

Comment: [Here is one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-2-TFT-LCD-and-Shield-for-Arduino-DUE-TAIJIUINO-DUE-with-SD-Touch-control-/130940301269?ssPageName=ADME:L:OC:US:3160) from Elechouse in China on eBay, $30 3.2" TFT Color LCD with touch stylus and using the Adafruit GFX library.  Demo worked first try, instructions and software on the eBay page.

Comment: @Bob How responsive is it? Does it take a few moments to load new pictures? Resistive touchscreen?

Comment: @Anon you mean responsive to touch?  Interactive animation?  I don't recall any want for responsiveness but I only fired the demo up once.  I recall seeing a photo image and using the stylus in a simple "draw" program like in the eBay photos.  I could connect and load it again if you have anything specific you'd like me to look for.  I only got it working in the Arduino IDE, hadn't yet ported it to my favored AtmelStudio IDE.

Answer (score 5):

There's also a [2.2" Adafruit TFT](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1480).

The nice things about the Adafruit displays are:
i) library support for both the [display](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ILI9340) and the [graphics core library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GFX-Library). So it's easy to get it up and running.

The built in frame buffer reduces resource requirements on Arduino.

Answer (score 2):

Another very cool screen is the official [Arduino TFT LCD Screen](http://store.arduino.cc/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=288#.UwlAY_kiEw8). ([Datasheet](http://arduino.cc/documents/datasheets/A000096_Datasheet_HTF0177SN-01-SPEC.pdf) if you're curious.)

It's a 1.77" screen, with a resolution of 160x128. It has a micro-SD slot in it, which is easily accessible. It is a color screen, with up to 18 bit per pixel.

The extremely nice thing with this screen is that since it's officially supported, you don't need to do anything extra to support it. The [official Arduino TFT library](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/TFTLibrary#.UwlB__kiEw8) works perfectly with it. However, according to [Jameco](http://www.jameco.com/1/1/52373-a000096-tft-lcd-screen-runs-5vdc-shields.html):

> Library Update: There is a known issue with the TFT library supplied
>   in IDE versions 1.0.5 and 1.5.4 Beta. You will need to replace the
>   library. We have zipped up the updated TFT library for both versions
>   available here. Just delete the existing library and copy in the
>   replacement for the appropriate IDE version and restart the IDE. (IDE
>   v1.0.5 or v1.5.4)

So beside that minor fix, everything should be easy and quick to work with. [This page](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/TFTLibrary#.UwlB__kiEw8) has some code samples which should make it easy to work with.